# Python: Issues with "if not any"

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, any

I have a problem with the Python function `any()`. I want to use the `any()` function to remove from a list any items that contains a digit. For instance:

`lst = ['abc123','qwerty','123','hello']`

and I apply the following code to remove from `lst` the items: `'abc123'`,`'123'`

`new_list = [item for item in lst if not any(item.isdigit() for char in item)]`

I want `new_list` to contain only the items `['qwerty','hello']` but it turns out that `new_list`=`lst`...there is no change. Why? I also tried using `import __builtin__` and `__builtin__.any` and no luck. I use Python 2.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ned to check against `char`, not `item`, inside your `any`:

```
new_list = [item for item in lst if not any(char.isdigit() for char in item)]
```

Alternatively, you can use the `re` regex module:

```
new_list = [item for item in lst if not re.search(r'\d', item)]
```

Comment: ah! dumb me... Thanks I will approve your answer when the system allows me (I have to wait 8 min).

Answer (score 3):

`item.isdigit()` should be `char.isdigit()`.